# Inject a generic interface in a MVC contoller

Tags: c#, generics, model-view-controller, interface, asp.net-mvc-5

Here is what I am trying to do:
I have a generic interface

```
IGenInterface<T>
{
    T DoSomething()
}
```

And a class that implements that generic interface

```
class GenClass<T> : IGenInterface<T> 
{
    T DoSomething()
    { 
       ....
    }
}
```

And I have a MVC controller

```
class FooController : Controller
{
   FooController(IGenInterface<T> gen)

}
```

The compiler says that I need to specify a type. When I try to do:

```
class FooController<T> : Controller
{
...
}
```

The class and the interface are being both registered in Autofac but the actions in the controller are not being found when I try to request them. Is there a way I can inject a generic interface in a MVC controller.

Comment: You cannot have generic controllers. And you need to specify an actual type with a generic type argument in order to inject an object of that type.

Comment: Prior to generics, we just used object as the type. However this is not a adviseable pattern. Generics exist specifically so we no longer **have** to use Object. | As a  general rule, with Generic code you only have access to that wich is the "smalest common Denominator". So you have a incentive to be as specific as possible with types, using constraints.